# Can i set a site column which have been created using the UI, to be hidden in EditForm using powershell

Tags: 2013, powershell, administration, site-column

I am working on sharepoint server 2013. now i have created multiple site columns using the UI. Now when creating these site columns using the UI i can set if the column if Required or not. but i not not have the ability to set if the column is visible on Edit, view, Create forms, and to get these settings i have to create the site column using power-shell.

so my question is if i create a site column using the UI, can i updated its property such as "`ShowInDisplayForm`" using powershell later on ? or the site column need to be created using powershell from the beginning to be able to change its "`ShowInDisplayForm`" or "`ShowInEditForm`" , etc ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can update the property later on if you have already created the filed using UI. The code would be as below:

```
$list = (Get-SPWeb "http://yoursite").Lists |? {$_.Title -eq "yourlist"}

 $field = $list.Fields["yourfield"]

 $field.ShowInNewForm = $false //$true

 $field.ShowInEditForm = $false //$true

 $field.ShowInDisplayForm = $false //$true

 $field.Update()
```

There is no dependency on how or using which method you created the column.